# Why does opening an MS Excel file change the SHA hash of a document?

Tags: excel, sha

I want to verify that the contents of an Excel document have not been altered. I was thinking about using SHA hashes to do this. However, just the process of opening an Excel document changes the SHA hash of the file.

What is Excel 2011 changing in the file? Is there some way of preventing this from happening?

Comment: It's changing meta-data in the file properties such as editing time, last author etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just tested this quickly and if you set the file to be read-only, it does more or less what you want.

```
Create spreadsheet, save, set as read-only
Generate SHA-1 hash -> hash1

Open spreadsheet, edit, attempt save, receive warning about read-only copy, abort save, close without saving
Generate SHA-1 hash -> hash1 (i.e. same hash as before)

Turn off read-only flag, open, edit, save, undo edit, save, close
Generate SHA-1 hash -> hash2 (i.e. different hash from before)
```

So if you mark the file as read-only, this should allow people to view it without affecting the hash. If they turn the read-only flag off and open it, even if they do not make any changes, the hash will change.